# Why files are not transfered (saved?) properly between client in C# and server in C via tcp?

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, network-programming

I've set up TCP client in C# and server in C.
When I want to transfer file, some packets are lost and file is not saved properly.

I've compared PDF file I tried to transfer and half of packets were not saved, so I couldn't open it on another computer.

client code:

```
public void SendFile(string file, string destPath = "C:\\")
    {
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] filebuff = new byte[bufferSize];
        string fileName = destPath + file;

        //send to TcpServer request to send file
        stream.Write(textToBytes("RECEIVEFILE"), 0, 11);
        try
        {
            FileStream streamFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(streamFile);


            //send file name to TcpServer
            stream.Write(textToBytes(file), 0, file.Length);


            //get file size
            long filesize = streamFile.Length;

            //send file size to TcpServer
           //sendData(stream, BitConverter.GetBytes(filesize));

            //if file doesn't exist
            if (file == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.");
            }

            //if file is empty
            if (filesize == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File size: 0");
                return;
            }


            int totalLength = Convert.ToInt32(filesize);

            Console.WriteLine("Totallength: " + totalLength);
            long numberOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(streamFile.Length) / bufferSize));
            int currentPacketLength;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPackets; i++)
            {
                if (filesize > bufferSize)
                {
                    currentPacketLength = bufferSize;
                    totalLength = totalLength - currentPacketLength;
                }
                else
                    currentPacketLength = totalLength;

                filebuff = new byte[currentPacketLength];
                //streamFile.Read(filebuff, 0, currentPacketLength);
                binReader.Read(filebuff, 0, currentPacketLength);


                stream.Write(filebuff, 0, filebuff.Length);
            }

            streamFile.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There's no file...");
        }


    }

    public void DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] fileNameBytes;
        long received = 0;
        long receivedAll = 0;
        byte[] fileData = new byte[1024];

        stream.Write(textToBytes("SENDFILE"), 0, 8);
        fileNameBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);

        stream.Write(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameBytes.Length);
        byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[4];
        stream.Read(fileSizeBytes, 0, fileSizeBytes.Length);
        int bytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeBytes, 0);

        Console.WriteLine("I'm downloading file...");

        while (receivedAll < bytes)
        {
            received = stream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            if (received < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                break;
            }
            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("C:\\" + fileName, FileMode.Append));
            bWrite.Write(fileData);
            bWrite.Close();
            receivedAll += received;

        }

        if(receivedAll == bytes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File downloaded successfuly.");
        }
    }
```

server code:

```
void ReceiveFile(int client_socket)
{
const int buffsize = 1024;
char buff[buffsize];
long filesize, received = 0, receivedall;
char filenamechar[512];

std::string filename, fullFilename;
memset(filenamechar, 0, 512);
 /*
    if(recv(client_socket, filenamechar, 512, 0) != 512)
{
    printf("Error - filename.\n");
    return;
}

fullFilename = "/Users/xxx/" + std::string(filenamechar);

*
if(recv(client_socket, &filesize, sizeof(long), 0) != sizeof(long))
{
    printf("Child process: error.\n");
    return;
}*/

filesize = 331776;

std::fstream fileFromClient;

fullFilename = "/Users/xxx/sockets.pdf";

fileFromClient.open(fullFilename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

receivedall = 0;
while (receivedall < filesize)
{
    memset(buff, 0, 1024);
    received = recv(client_socket, buff, 1024, 0);
    if(received <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    receivedall += received;

    fileFromClient << buff;
    fputs(buff, stdout);
}

fileFromClient.close();

std::cout << "\nreceivedall: " << receivedall << std::endl;
std::cout << "filesize: " << filesize << std::endl;
if(receivedall != filesize)
    printf("Error\n");
else
    printf("File saved successfuly\n");

}

void SendFile(int client_socket)
{
char path[512];
char fileName[512];
char fullFileName[512];
long fileLen, sent, sentAll, read;
struct stat fileinfo;
FILE* file;
unsigned char bufor[1024];

memset(path, 0, 512);
strcpy(path, "/Users/xxxx/");

if (recv(client_socket, fileName, 512, 0) <= 0)
{
    printf("Child process: error\n");
    return;
}

strcpy(fullFileName, strcat(path, fileName));
printf("Child process: client wants file: %s\n", fullFileName);


if (stat(fullFileName, &fileinfo) < 0)
{
    printf("Child process: can't get file info\n");
    return;
}

if (fileinfo.st_size == 0)
{
    printf("Child process: file size: 0\n");
    return;
}

fileLen = fileinfo.st_size;

if (send(client_socket, &fileLen, sizeof(long), 0) != sizeof(long))
{
    printf("Child process: error\n");
    return;
}

sentAll = 0;
file = fopen(fullFileName, "rb");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    return;
}

while (sentAll < fileLen)
{
    read = fread(bufor, 1, 1024, file);
    sent = send(client_socket, bufor, read, 0);
    if (read != sent)
        break;
    sentAll += sent;
    printf("Child process: sent %ld bytes\n", sentAll);
}

if (sentAll == fileLen)
    printf("Child process: file sent successfuly\n");
else
    printf("Child process: error\n");
fclose(file);
return;    
}
```

How to guarantee that each packet will be saved properly?

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself a call to `memset` with `char filenamechar[512] = {0};` This will initialize the first space in the array with whatever number you put in the `{}`s and fill the rest of the array with zeros.

Comment: The receive doesn't know where the data ends.  So you must precede sending the data with the size.  then on the receive end remove the size and read until you get all the bytes.

Comment: Unrelated: save yourself another `memset`and a bit of other trouble by changing `received = recv(client_socket, buff, 1024, 0);` to `received = recv(client_socket, buff, sizeof(buff)-1, 0);`. `sizeof(buff)` removes the magic number 1024, placing the maximum size of the read in lockstep with the size of the buffer so you can't change the size of `buff` and then forget to change the amount to read. The -1 ensures you have space for a null terminator otherwise `fileFromClient << buff;` is high-risk. 1/2

Comment: You should not write the data with the formatting  `<<`, which expects zero-terminated strings.

Comment: 2/2 To get the null terminator, `buff[received] = '\0';` instead of wasting time setting the whole buffer to nulls.

Comment: In `SendFile`, `if (recv(client_socket, fileName, 512, 0) <= 0)` gives no guarantees that the whole of the file name will be read and that you won't get part of a future message that wound up in the same TCP packet. This makes `strcpy(fullFileName, strcat(path, fileName));` into quite an adventure. You need a protocol  that establishes how much data needs to be read and loop until you have all of it. You could play get-a-byte until you find a null terminator, but prefixing the string with the size of the string in an integer of  known size and endian is usually more elegant.

Comment: `if (send(client_socket, &fileLen, sizeof(long), 0) != sizeof(long))` is the flip side of the last problem. You're sending the length, but instead of using `long` you need to make sure you send an integer of a known length `int64_t` for example and you need to make sure both sides agree on the byte order of the integer (the endian).

Answer (score 1):

One problem is with this line:

```
fileFromClient << buff;
```

This will write out the contents of `buff` until a zero byte is found.  Since your are transferring a binary file, you can expect these bytes to be frequent.  The rest of the received packet will not be written.

Rather than using the `<<` operator, you should use

```
fileFromClient.write(buff, received);
```